# Using Q expression in Case When is not returning expected results in Django. Seems like an inner join is used, not left join

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to build a complex filter with the Django ORM and am running into an issue where objects without a foreign key are not being included. This is due to an inner join that is being generated and I believe it should be a left outer join. I have two models Report and Message. Report has a reference to a particular Message but that could also be null.

```
class Report(BaseModel):
    
    message = models.ForeignKey(
        Message,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="message_reports",
        null=True,
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField()

    # other fields

class Message(BaseModel):

    should_send_messages = models.BooleanField(
        default=True
    )

    num_hold_hours = models.IntegerField(
        default=None,
        null=True,
    )

    # other fields
```

Here is the filter that I am trying to use.

```
        Report.objects.filter(
            Q(message__isnull=True) | Q(message__should_send_messages=True),
            created_at__lte=
            Case(
                When(
                    Q(message__isnull=True) | Q(message__num_hold_hours__isnull=True),
                    then=ExpressionWrapper(
                        timezone.now() - timedelta(hours=1) * Cast(
                            settings.NUM_HOURS_TO_NOTIFY
                            , output_field=IntegerField())
                        , output_field=DateTimeField())),
                default=ExpressionWrapper(
                    timezone.now() - timedelta(hours=1) * Cast(
                        F('message__num_hold_hours')
                        , output_field=IntegerField())
                    , output_field=DateTimeField()),
                output_field=DateTimeField()),
        )
```

Here is the sql that is generated as a result of that filter block. (I'm not sure why the datetimes look like that ugly)

```
SELECT "report"."message_id"
FROM "report"
    INNER JOIN "message" ON (
        "report"."message_id" = "message"."id"
    )
WHERE (
        (
            "report"."message_id" IS NULL
            OR "message"."should_send_messages" = True
        )
        AND "report"."created_at" <= (
            CASE
                WHEN (
                    "report"."message_id" IS NULL
                    OR "message"."num_hold_hours" IS NULL
                ) THEN (
                    2020 -11 -24 07 :09 :22.401276 + 00 :00 - (1 :00 :00 * (48)::integer)
                )
                ELSE (
                    2020 -11 -24 07 :09 :22.401833 + 00 :00 - (
                        1 :00 :00 * ("message"."num_hold_hours")::integer
                    )
                )
            END
        )
    )
ORDER BY "report"."created_at" DESC
```

I believe the output of that sql query should be.

```
SELECT "report"."message_id"
FROM "report"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "message" ON (
        "report"."message_id" = "message"."id"
    )
WHERE (
        (
            "report"."message_id" IS NULL
            OR "message"."should_send_messages" = True
        )
        AND "report"."created_at" <= (
            CASE
                WHEN (
                    "report"."message_id" IS NULL
                    OR "message"."num_hold_hours" IS NULL
                ) THEN (
                    2020 -11 -24 07 :09 :22.401276 + 00 :00 - (1 :00 :00 * (48)::integer)
                )
                ELSE (
                    2020 -11 -24 07 :09 :22.401833 + 00 :00 - (
                        1 :00 :00 * ("message"."num_hold_hours")::integer
                    )
                )
            END
        )
    )
ORDER BY "report"."created_at" DESC
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked at this using annotate with a FilteredRelation ?

Comment: I have tried to use FilteredRelation which will give me a left join in some cases. However, that left join was usually in addition to an inner join, so I ran into the same issue.